# How to save current url using javascript?

Tags: javascript, imacros

I am searching for such method to save the current url of the webpage to a file. after alot search I found this working script:

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !EXTRACTADD {{!URLCURRENT}}
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=c:\ FILE=URL.CSV
```

But the point is that how to use this in javascript . I just tried as following :

```
var link;

link +="SET !ERRORIGNORE YES";
link +="SET !EXTRACTADD {{!URLCURRENT}}";
link +="SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=c:\ FILE=URL.CSV";
```

But this is not working for me. I am just a noob , Help me out with a easy way :)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why is this upvoted? This is complete gibberish...

Answer (score 0):

If it is in a new file, just have a file on the server that has the URL, create a link to the file and have it downloaded on the local computer.  With JavaScript, you can initialize the process automatically, but the visitor will have to participate.  Having a file written silently on the local machine is not something possible for security reason, unless it is a cookie or session data - these are special files in some reserved area, which can be accessed later on by the browser.  Why do you need the URL for?